# Полное форматирование незанятых областей диска

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файлы, администрирование

У меня есть RAID 1 на 2 HDD на mdadm. Я долгое время удалял с него файлы обычным путём, и сейчас потребовалось зашифровать все данные на нём в целях безопасности. Однако я понимаю, что те файлы, которые я удалял всё еще физически записаны на диске.

Есть ли какой-то способ пройтись глубоким форматированием не по всему диску, а только лишь по всему свободному пространству на нём, не задевая существующие файлы?

Comment: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=nonexistent-yet-file.dat; rm -f nonexistent-yet-file.dat`, но я не уверен, как именно вы отличаете мелкое форматирование от глубокого.

Comment: @user_587 под глубоким формотированием я имел ввиду перезапись ячеек памяти, чтобы их нельзя было восстановить, а не просто забывание указателя на файл. А что за `nonexistent-yet-file.dat`? Надо создать какой-то конкретный файл, занимающий всю оставшиюся память?

Comment: Да, он как раз и создаётся этой последовательностью, а потом удаляется. Вопрос "можно-нельзя восстановить" дискуссионный, имейте в виду. "Ячейки памяти" и "HDD", в моём понимании — взаимоисключающие понятия; мой ответ относится именно к HDD.